# Autoquery CRUD for batch operations

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

Is there any practice using `ServiceStack AutoQuery Crud` to post multiple `CreateDb<T>` requests to insert in single transaction multiple rows (Auto Batched Requests?)?

UPDATE: I have tried to use @mythz solution but custom service for processing batching requests of type ICreateDb results in exception `ResolutionException`:

`"Required dependency of type aproject.core.ServiceInterface.Services.ProjectContractsService could not be resolved."`

`Funq.ResolutionException: Required dependency of type aproject.core.ServiceInterface.Services.ProjectContractsService could not be resolved.   at ServiceStack.Host.ContainerResolveCache.CreateInstance(IResolver resolver, Type type, Boolean tryResolve) in C:\BuildAgent\work\3481147c480f4a2f\src\ServiceStack\Host\ContainerResolveCache.cs:line 60   at ServiceStack.Host.ContainerResolveCache.CreateInstance(IResolver resolver, Type type) in C:\BuildAgent\work\3481147c480f4a2f\src\ServiceStack\Host\ContainerResolveCache.cs:line 34   at ServiceStack.Host.ServiceController.<>c__DisplayClass41_0.<RegisterServiceExecutor>g__HandlerFn|0(IRequest req, Object dto) in C:\BuildAgent\work\3481147c480f4a2f\src\ServiceStack\Host\ServiceController.cs:line 437   at ServiceStack.Host.ServiceController.ExecuteAsync(Object requestDto, IRequest req) in C:\BuildAgent\work\3481147c480f4a2f\src\ServiceStack\Host\ServiceController.cs:line 674   at ServiceStack.Host.Handlers.GenericHandler.ProcessRequestAsync(IRequest httpReq, IResponse httpRes, String operationName) in C:\BuildAgent\work\3481147c480f4a2f\src\ServiceStack\Host\Handlers\GenericHandler.cs:line 62`

The Autoquery is registered correctlly but I have found that my ICreateDb DTO for crating the entries is registered multiple times:

`DEBUG: Registering OneWay service 'ContractsService' with request 'CreateContractEstimate[]' DEBUG: Registering Reply service '__AutoQueryServices' with request 'CreateContractEstimate'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just implemented support for auto implementing batch implementations for all CRUD operations which will by default execute all AutoQuery CRUD Requests within a DB transaction.

By default it will generate AutoBatch implementations for all CRUD operations and can be changed to only generate implementations for specific CRUD operations by changing:

```
Plugins.Add(new AutoQueryFeature {
    GenerateAutoBatchImplementationsFor = new() { AutoCrudOperation.Create }
});
```

It also wont generate implementations for custom AutoBatch implementations, e.g. you can add a custom implementation that does what the generated implementation would've done and execute using the same DB Connection and Transaction with:

```
public class CustomAutoQueryServices : Service
{
    public IAutoQueryDb AutoQuery { get; set; }

    public object Any(CreateItem[] requests)
    {
        using var db = AutoQuery.GetDb<Item>(Request);
        using var dbTrans = db.OpenTransaction();

        var results = new List<object>();
        foreach (var request in requests)
        {
            var response = await AutoQuery.CreateAsync(request, Request, db);
            results.Add(response);
        }

        dbTrans.Commit();
        return results;            
    }
}
```

and as [AutoQuery Services](https://docs.servicestack.net/autoquery) are just normal ServiceStack Services you can re-use the existing Service Client support for [Auto Batched Requests](https://docs.servicestack.net/auto-batched-requests), e.g:

```
var client = new JsonServiceClient(BaseUrl);
var response = client.SendAll(new CreateItem[] { ... });
```

This feature is available from v5.11.1 that's now [available on MyGet](https://docs.servicestack.net/myget).

Comment: I will try your suggestion @mythz - I need also to extend service to have built in merge support (i.e possibility to send some elements which are alredy in db, ignore them if exists and insert only new, remove items which are not send in the request)

Comment: I was not able to use yours suggested solution because of service error when trying to post array of ICreateDb requests.

Comment: @marcinn The error says that one of the dependencies of your `ProjectContractsService` failed to be resolved, do you have AutoQuery configured & can you manually call any API on your `ProjectContractsService` class?

Comment: the `ProjectContractService` works fine for some test DTO HelloWorld which I have created, also AutqueryDb is commonly used in my project and works fine for queing and modifing data. Only the method call for array of ICreateDb items fails with this dependency exception :(

Comment: @marcinn Are you able to call `container.TryResolve<aproject.core.ServiceInterface.Services.ProjectContractsService>()` in your AppHost Configure()?

Comment: @myhz the service is resolved properly but  `public IAutoQueryDb AutoQuery { get; set; }` is null. Not sure why it is not resolved in the custom service since I use in my project multiple queries and command dtos (implementing ICreateDb, Query<>) without any issue.

Comment: I have just added line after registering it in Plugins collection   `Plugins.Add(autoQuery);` the autoquery `autoQuery.Register(this); ` in the `AppHost.Configure` and now it works...

Comment: BTW I have also discovered ISaveDb interface - all is good!

Comment: @marcinn great happy to hear it

Comment: @marcinn FYI see updated answer showing latest ServiceStack v5.11.1 on MyGet is now generating AutoBatch implementations for all CRUD operations to execute with the same DB Connection + Transaction.